# I can't get announcements related to that particular category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm trying to get announcements related to that selected category.

This is my code.

*View:*

```
  @foreach ($categories as $category)
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('public.announcements.category', [$category->id]) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                        @endforeach
```

*Controller:*

```
    public function announcementsByCategory($category_id)
    {
        $category = Category::find($category_id);
        $announcements = $category->announcements()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('announcements', compact('category', 'announcements'));
    }
}
```

*Route:*

`Route::get('/category/{id}/announcements', [PublicController::class,'announcementsByCategory'])->name('public.announcements.category');`

I am getting the following error on $announcements:

**Call to a member function announcements() on null**

Can anyone kindly tell me why I get this error?
I started learning Laravel recently.

Comment: it can't find your category by the `$category_id` you are providing ... `find` can return `null`

Comment: @lagbox I have not understood. Can you explain me better kindly?

Comment: `Category::find($category_id)` is returning `null` which means it can't find your record

Comment: Yes, OK. But I'm not understanding why

Comment: try `dd($category_id)` at the beginning of the controller method, to check whether the id is passed correctly or not

Comment: yes, $category_id is passed correctly

Comment: Right after the find, try adding a `dd($category);` to see all the information, or it will be null if not found.

Comment: @PaulT. the category is printed with all the information

Comment: Ok, so is the relation information to `announcements` in the `dd` too?

Comment: yes, everything is present